# Get the top categories for each value in the column aside with one single query

Tags: mysql, sql

Say we have a table looking as follows:

```
country    product     order
France     cheese      1
UK         cheese      2
Germany    sausage     3
UK         beer        4
UK         beer        5
France     wine        6
France     pork        7
France     wine        8
Germany    pork        9
UK         butter      10
UK         cheese      11
Germany    pork        12
Germany    butter      13
UK         beer        14
France     cheese      15
UK         cheese      16
Germany    butter      17
```

My aim is to tweak this table so I could get the two more repeated products for each country. If possible, using one single query. The outcome should look like this:

```
country    product   count
France     cheese    2
France     wine      2
UK         beer      3
UK         cheese    3
Germany    pork      2
Germany    butter    2
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `GROUP BY country, product` to count the number of orders and then use RANK() window function to get the top 2 products for each country:

```
SELECT country, product, count
FROM (
  SELECT country, product, COUNT(*) count,
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY country ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rnk
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY country, product
) t
WHERE rnk <= 2
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d045f007d83011a594799d0a822706a3).
Results:

```
> country | product | count
> :------ | :------ | ----:
> France  | cheese  |     2
> France  | wine    |     2
> Germany | pork    |     2
> Germany | butter  |     2
> UK      | cheese  |     3
> UK      | beer    |     3
```

Answer (score 2):

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS (SELECT DISTINCT 
                country, 
                product, 
                COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY country, product) cnt
         FROM test),
cte2 AS (SELECT country, 
                product, 
                cnt, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country ORDER BY cnt DESC) rn
         FROM cte1)
SELECT country, 
       product, 
       cnt 
FROM cte2 
WHERE rn < 3;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0ad21438618a153f05160e051dfc0e53)

PS. If 2nd and 3rd (4th, 5th, ...) rows have the same amount of rows then indefinite (think as random) of them will be returned.